# Getting closest target image in Vuforia

Tags: opengl-es, matrix, vuforia

I'm using the video playback Vuforia example for building an app. When the app recognises multiple image targets I would like to know which is the closest one to the centre of the screen (which is supposed to be my camera view). In the source code I have found this line:

```
const QCAR::Matrix34F & QCAR::TrackableResult::getPose()
```

which gives me a 3x4 pose matrix of the target. How can use this matrix for extracting this information?

thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This Vuforia [Knowledge database article](https://developer.vuforia.com/resources/dev-guide/pose-matrix-explained) explains in detail the meaning of the pose matrix, you should probably have a look at it.

To make it short, the pose matrix is a 3x4 matrix whose last column is the translation vector `<x,y,z>` from the camera to the detected target. The "closest target to the center of the screen" should thus be the one with the smallest `<x,y>` vector.

Hope this helps!